# Selection is not declared, but no idea how to declare it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word, interop, vsto

All, I am getting the following error in visual studio: "Selection is not declared."

I am trying to make a simple word application in vb that allows me to find and replace multiple values in a document. I am aware that the selection should be the entire content of the document, and I have been researching on MSDN but I must be missing something because I have been unable to find out what exactly I should do to declare which selection to search.

I have two items in my project:

**ThisDocument.vb:**

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.Select
Public Class ThisDocument
    Private Sub ThisDocument_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        Me.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
        Me.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text = "This text was added programmatically."
    End Sub
    Private Sub ThisDocument_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
    End Sub
End Class
```

**and Charm.vb (Which is a ribbon item):**

```
Option Explicit On
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindMatch
Public Class Charm

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim custNum As String = TB_CustNum.Text
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting()
            .Text = "care"
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting()
            .Replacement.Text = custNum
            .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True,
                Wrap:=wdFindContinue)
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is happening on line 14 of Charm.vb. Any help would be appreciated.***Thank you :)***

EDIT:

After adding a namespace reference for Word, I am now getting the following error on the same line:

**Error BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.**

Comment: `Selection` is a member of `Word.Application` - you can't use it without qualifying it via Interop, because the global objects aren't available like they are in Word VBA.

Comment: You may have to add reference for Word.Application

Comment: I am now getting the following error: Error BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: Where are you creating the `Word.Application` object?

Comment: No, i am getting that same error on line 14. So line 14 is giving me an error stating: "reference to non-shared member requires an object reference".

Comment: Right, I realize *where* you're getting the error.  The error is telling you that you need to call the method of an *object*.  Are you creating a `Word.Application` *object* somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selection with something like ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386206.aspx))

```
Dim selection = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection
```

but working with the selection is prone to many errors and isn't always a `Range`
Instead, you can use a Range variable:

```
Dim doc as Document = Globals.ThisDocument

Dim range As Range = doc.Range  ' this is the main story Range without Headers and Footers

With range.Find
    .Execute(FindText:="care", ReplaceWith:=custNum, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, 
             Forward:=True, Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindContinue)
End With
```